# Spring MVC testing with JUnit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, junit4

I'm trying to do some test for my repository, but I'm getting a `NullPointerException`.

Interface:

```
public interface PersonneRepository {
    void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory);
    Personne findByLoginInformations(String email, String password);
}
```

Interface implementation:

```
@Repository
    public class PersonneRepositoryImpl implements PersonneRepository {

        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @Autowired
        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }

        public Personne findByLoginInformations(String email, String password){
            Session session;
            try {
                session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            }
            Query query = session
                    .createQuery("FROM Personne p WHERE p.email = :email AND p.password = :password")
                    .setParameter("email", email)
                    .setParameter("password", password);
            return (Personne)query.uniqueResult();
        }
    }
```

Test class :

```
public class PersonneRepositoryTest {

    @Mock
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @InjectMocks
    private PersonneRepositoryImpl personneRepositoryImpl;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindPersonne(){
        Personne p = new Personne();
        p.setId(1);
        when(personneRepositoryImpl.findByLoginInformations("ayoub", "aaaa")).thenReturn(p);
        assertEquals(p, personneRepositoryImpl.findById(1));
        verify(personneRepositoryImpl).findById(1);
    }
}
```

Here's the error message:

java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.eheio.hello.repositories.impl.PersonneRepositoryImpl.findByLoginInformations(PersonneRepositoryImpl.java:77)
        at com.eheio.hello.repositories.PersonneRepositoryTest.testFindPersonne(PersonneRepositoryTest.java:31)

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting the following

- @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) to the Test Class
- Mock session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
- Mock .setParameter("password", password); for Query
- Then in the same statement, mock for .setParameter("email", email) using then
- Mock for .createQuery("FROM Personne p WHERE p.email = :email AND p.password = :password")
- Mock for query.uniqueResult()
- For personneRepositoryImpl.findByLoginInformations("ayoub", "aaaa") should NOT be mocked. Must be called.
- Finally assert.

Hope, it might help you.